# Testing Restful Webservice with continuous integration and cleaning the Database

Tags: java, web-services, rest, testing, integration-testing

I'm searching for tools to test my restful service. The restful Service is written in Java and the code for the tests should be also Java or something similar like Javascript.

The spezial thing to that should be that we Test on a real Database. After each Test the Database should be in the same state as before.

The software should do something like Transaction handeling. But if we test the connection from outside (like with a normal HTTP Request) we cant do just "normal" Transaction handeling like SpringJunit4ClassRunner.

Some ideas?

Comment: ...dump and restore the database?

Comment: I want to do it automatically between every test. Not just once every time I test...